# How to crawl a website based on algolia-AJAX?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, algolia

I am trying to crawl the listings on this website via scrapy: https://www.hipflat.com/search/rent/condo_y/TH.BM_r1/any_r2/any_p/any_b/any_a/any_w/any_i/100.560155,13.737171_c/16_z/list_v

However, I am stuck with the navigation. At the bottom of the page the links for "next page" show up. But as far as I can see it, they call an external site (algolia) via a JavaScrip-Query.

What would be the easiest way to make the navigation crawlable via scrapy?

Answer (score 1):

The next page link is present in the page. You can get it using `response.css("[rel='next']" ::attr("href"))`. This will provide you the next link for pagination. Now you can simply proceed with `GET` request using `response.follow(url=,callback=)`.

Comment: Hi Irkam, I tried this already, but it doesn't work… a click on the link calls a special java-script, which then redirects to the new page… any idea about how to handle that?